# Euca 5 Ansible Install Skipping Node Actions

Tags: eucalyptus

I'm trying to use the Euca 5 ansible installer to install a single server for all services "exp-euca.lan.com" with two node controllers "exp-enc-[01:02].lan.com" running VPCMIDO.  The install goes okay and I end up with a single server running all Euca services including being able to run instances but the ansible scripts never take action to install and configure my node servers.  I think I'm misunerdstanding the inventory format.  What could be wrong with the following? I don't want my main euca server to run instances and I do want the two node controllers installed and running instances.

```html
---
all:
  hosts:
    exp-euca.lan.com:
    exp-enc-[01:02].lan.com:

  vars:
    vpcmido_public_ip_range: "192.168.100.5-192.168.100.254"
    vpcmido_public_ip_cidr: "192.168.100.1/24"
    cloud_system_dns_dnsdomain: "cloud.lan.com"
    cloud_public_port: 443 
    eucalyptus_console_cloud_deploy: yes
    cloud_service_image_rpm: no
    cloud_properties:
      services.imaging.worker.ntp_server: "x.x.x.x"
      services.loadbalancing.worker.ntp_server: "x.x.x.x"


  children:
    cloud:
      hosts:
        exp-euca.lan.com:
    console:
      hosts:
        exp-euca.lan.com:
    zone:
      hosts:
        exp-euca.lan.com:
    nodes:
      hosts:
        exp-enc-[01:02].lan.com:
```

All of the plays related to nodes have a pattern similar to this where they succeed and acknowledge the main server exp-euca but then skip the nodes.

```html
2021-01-14 08:15:23,572 p=57513 u=root n=ansible | TASK [zone assignments default] ***********************************************************************************************************************
2021-01-14 08:15:23,596 p=57513 u=root n=ansible | ok: [exp-euca.lan.com] => (item=[0, u'exp-euca.lan.com']) => {"ansible_facts": {"host_zone_key": "1"}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": [0, "exp-euca.lan.com"]}
2021-01-14 08:15:23,604 p=57513 u=root n=ansible | skipping: [exp-enc-01.lan.com] => (item=[0, u'exp-euca.lan.com'])  => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": [0, "exp-euca.lan.com"], "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `node`, not `nodes`, i.e.:

```
node:
  hosts:
    exp-enc-[01:02].lan.com:
```

The [documentation](https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/5/install_guide/automated_install/) for this is currently incorrect.